# What is a request as defined by Windows Azure

Tags: azure, analytics

I'm a project manager not a developer, and we stood up a really basic site in windows azure, We've now been asked to track usage of the site, and I'm curious what a request is.  The site is accessed through a mobile device and performs a basic calculation.  So I believe that there is only one request per visit, changing numbers you enter in various fields to what if the calculation doesn't seem to refresh the page.  Is that a fair assumption or are there some basic checks I can do to understand if I need to aggregate requests to really track or interpret usage of the site.

Answer (score 0):

> Whenever your web browser fetches a file (a page, a picture, etc) from
>   a web server, it does so using HTTP - that's "Hypertext Transfer
>   Protocol".  HTTP is a request/response protocol, which means your
>   computer sends a request for some file (e.g. "Get me the file
>   'home.html'"), and the web server sends back a response ("Here's the
>   file", followed by the file itself).
>
> That request which your computer sends to the web server contains all
>   sorts of (potentially) interesting information.  We'll now examine the
>   HTTP request your computer just sent to this web server, see what it
>   contains, and find out what it tells me about you.

http://djce.org.uk/dumprequest

tip: add google analytics to your site. It will give to you the number of views and unique users.